# SQL Server 2008 Express restore different

Tags: sql-server, diff, restore

**SERVER 1**

Backup FULL

```
USE master;  

ALTER DATABASE Parking SET RECOVERY FULL;  
GO  

-- Back up the Parking database to new media set (backup set 1).  
BACKUP DATABASE Parking  
TO DISK = 'c:\backup\parking.bak'   
WITH FORMAT;  
GO  

--Create a routine log backup (backup set 2).  
BACKUP LOG Parking TO DISK = 'c:\backup\parking.bak';  
GO
```

Backup DIFF

```
BACKUP DATABASE Parking TO DISK = 'C:\backup\dif.DIF' WITH DIFFERENTIAL
```

**SERVER 2**

Restore

```
ALTER DATABASE Parking SET RESTRICTED_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

USE Parking;

ALTER DATABASE Parking SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

USE tempdb;

DROP DATABASE Parking;

RESTORE DATABASE Parking 
FROM DISK = 'C:\backup\parking.bak' WITH NORECOVERY;
GO

RESTORE DATABASE Parking     
FROM DISK = 'C:\backup\dif.DIF' WITH RECOVERY;  
GO
```

Output in console:

```
Processed 122736 pages for database 'Parking', file 'Parking' on file 1.
Processed 381464 pages for database 'Parking', file 'FG_RECORD' on file 1.
Processed 14 pages for database 'Parking', file 'Parking_log' on file 1.
Processed 0 pages for database 'Parking', file 'Parking_media' on file 1.
RESTORE DATABASE successfully processed 504214 pages in 217.089 seconds (18.145 MB/sec).

1>   
2> Processed 320 pages for database 'Parking', file 'Parking' on file 1.
Processed 392 pages for database 'Parking', file 'FG_RECORD' on file 1.
Processed 7 pages for database 'Parking', file 'Parking_log' on file 1.
Processed 0 pages for database 'Parking', file 'Parking_media' on file 1.
RESTORE DATABASE successfully processed 719 pages in 11.613 seconds (0.483 MB/sec).
```

Full data exists in database, but DIFF data not add in database

Comment: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 reached end of life well over a year ago and are now **completely unsupported**. You really should be looking at upgrading to a supported version.

Comment: the program is delivered only in 2008, the developer does not plan to update

Answer (score 0):

The diff backup contains all/any changes that happened in the database since/AFTER the **last/latest** Full backup (excluding full backups taken WITH COPY_ONLY).

You could test that by making a change after the full backup and before the diff one:

```
--full backup
BACKUP DATABASE Parking  
TO DISK = 'c:\backup\parking.bak'   
WITH FORMAT;  
GO  

--a change after the full backup
create table Parking..footable(foocolumn bit)
go


--Backup DIFF : this will contain footable
BACKUP DATABASE Parking TO DISK = 'C:\backup\dif.DIF' WITH DIFFERENTIAL
go
```

Comment: so it happens, at night a full and during the day different is made and this different is not added to the database on the 2 server